# How to pass data to Angular2 Component from AngularFire2 Service

Tags: angular, electron, angularfire2

I am trying to grab the highest number from my list of product numbers in the inventory. I can query the list just fine, but what is confusing me is the async nature of using firebase, it has me confused as to why things are happening the way they are.

I am querying my database in a service that is injected into the add item component, where I want to retrieve the last item number and add 1 to it for the next item. Here is my component code, my template for said component, as well as the service to send the data:

## Add Item Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MdButtonModule} from '@angular/material';
import { Item } from './Item'
import {InventoryDataService} from '../../inventory-data.service';
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-additem',
  templateUrl: './additem.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./additem.component.scss']
})

export class AdditemComponent implements OnInit {
  public item: Item;
  itemsList: any;
  nextItemNumber: number;

  constructor(private itemData: InventoryDataService) {
    this.itemsList = itemData.getItems();
    this.item = {
      num: null,
      name: '',
      class: '',
      category: '',
      price: null,
      description: ''
    }
       this.getNextItemNumber()
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addItem() {
    this.itemData.addItem(this.item);
    console.log('added!');
  }

  getNextItemNumber() {
    this.item.num = this.itemData.number;
    console.log('Component Says The Number Is: ' + this.item.num);
  }

  get diagnostic() { return JSON.stringify(this.item); }
}
```

### Add Item Template

```
<form>
  <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input mdInput placeholder="Product Number" name="itemNumber" value="item.num" [(ngModel)]="item.num">
  </md-form-field>

  <p>
    <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input mdInput placeholder="Item Name" name="itemName" [(ngModel)]="item.name">
    </md-form-field>
    <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input mdInput placeholder="Item Description" name="itemDescription" [(ngModel)]="item.description">
    </md-form-field>
    <md-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input mdInput placeholder="Item Description" type="number" name="itemPrice" [(ngModel)]="item.price">
      </md-form-field>
  </p>

<md-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input mdInput placeholder="Class" name="itemClass" [(ngModel)]="item.class">
</md-form-field>
<md-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input mdInput placeholder="Category" name="itemCategory" [(ngModel)]="item.category">
    </md-form-field>
</form>

<div id='submit'>
  <button md-button type="submit" (click)="addItem()">Add!</button>
  <button md-button type="button" (click)="getNextItemNumber()">See Item Numbers</button>
</div>
<p>
    {{diagnostic}}
</p>
```

### Inventory Data Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {DataSource} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class InventoryDataService {
  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  itemNumbers: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  itemsObservable: DataSource<any>;
  number: any;


  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('/items');
    this.itemNumbers = db.list('/items',  { preserveSnapshot: true,
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'number',
        limitToLast: 1,
      }
    });
    console.log('Data Service Constructed!');

    this.itemNumbers.subscribe(snapshots => {
      snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
        this.number = snapshot.val().number;
        console.log('Number has been generated! Number Is: ' + this.number +  ' Snapshot Says: ' + snapshot.val().number);
      })
    })
   }

   getItems() {
     return this.items;
   }

   addItem(item: object) {
     this.items.push(item);
     console.log('Item Pushed: ' + item);
   }

}
```

Looking at my console.logs just make me more confused. I understand that async operations take time, but i thought that by subscribing to the data I am getting a promise that it will be resolved? The console.logs print in this order:

```
Data Service Constructed!
Component says the number is undefined
Number Has been Generated!
```

I get *why* this is happening (I have to wait for the server to send the data, and the following code executes too fast) but what I don't know is how to fix this. How do I tell angular to wait until the value is resolved before assigning the value?